# How to get payment method and other details from stripe paymentElement in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have the following, basic code for setting recurring payment in stripe.

```
await stripe
  ?.confirmSetup({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: url,
    },
  })
```

I was browsing the docs and the internet and could not find answer to two questions:

1. How do I get rid of the return_url, this is I guess the most annoying feature since I switched to PaymentElement from old CardElement
2. Is there any way to get paymentMethod.id from this operation? It seems impossible, other than later calling the user on the backend, listing the paymentMethods added to the profile.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How do I get rid of the return_url, this is I guess the most annoying feature since I switched to PaymentElement from old CardElement

The `return_url` parameter is always required and will be necessary if you use any payment methods that require a redirect. You can set `redirect: 'if_required'`[1] to tell Stripe.js to only redirect when necessary, which would mean that no redirect happens if the payment can be confirmed immediately or if the payment method's next steps can be completed in a modal. If you only use payment methods like cards it will completely prevent any redirect on success.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_setup#confirm_setup_intent-options-redirect

> 2. Is there any way to get paymentMethod.id from this operation? It seems impossible, other than later calling the user on the backend, listing the paymentMethods added to the profile.

Yes, if you set `redirect` to `if_required` the confirmSetup call will return a promise that resolves to a SetupIntent object. That SetupIntent will have a `payment_method` property with the new payment method's ID as its value.

Comment: What happens to the external methods then, like Klarna? (for Q2)

Comment: The user will still have to be redirected and then will return to your `return_url`. The non payment element Klarna integration for Stripe requires a return_url as well https://stripe.com/docs/payments/klarna/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=API